# posting json to express - invalid json

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am trying to post some json to a node server running express but it keeps telling me the json was invalid. But its not, its just a plain old object. Currently I get the error 'unexpected token i'

client:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin",
    data: {id: '435ghgf545ft5345', allowed: true}
});
```

server:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser({strict: false}));

app.post('/admin', function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.body);
});
```

I have also tried putting bodyParser.json() as the second parameter in the post route and get the error 'invalid json at parse'. I cant figure out why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code may help you :

```
var jsondataResource = JSON.stringify({id: '435ghgf545ft5345', allowed: true});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    async: false,
    url: '/admin', // Location of the service
    data: jsondataResource , //Data sent to server
    contentType: 'application/json', // content type sent to server
    dataType: 'json', //Expected data format from server
    processdata: true, //True or False
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (msg, textStatus, xmlHttp) {
        result = msg;
    },
    error: ServiceFailed  // When Service call fails
});
function ServiceFailed(result) {
alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
Type = null; Url = null; Data = null; ContentType = null; DataType = null; ProcessData = null;
}
```

Comment: Hey Sambath, thanks for this, it was in fact that I did not stringify my json, so the server was trying to parse an already parsed object.

Comment: please dont just post an arbitrary snippet of code. you need to explain why this is correct and what OP did wrong.

Comment: is this an omission in the jQuery docs, or just a peculiarity with express and bodyparser? Do all json objects need to be stringified when sent through jquery post?

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ shows an example with 

`$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });`